# Toggling an objects visibility off turns back on when the view layer is toggled off then on again?

Tags: interface, outliner

Not sure if this is a bug or intentional, when toggling a view layer off objects that were hidden in the collection become visible when the view layer is turned back on. This only seems to happen with "hide in viewport" option though.
Not sure what the point is in having a "hide in viewport" option as well as a "disable in viewport" seems kind of confusing. I would like the visibility to stay off when toggling the view layer.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'd say this is intentional, as it also affects hidden *sub-collections* in a similar way. On the other hand, objects/sub-collections that are *Disabled in Viewport* stay disabled. So, to keep the visibility off, I'd use the *Disable in Viewport*. option.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to just have to get in the habit of using the "disable viewport" option from now on.